# Bind property value to a textbox control within GridViewGroupFooterCell in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik, radgridview

I'm trying to bind the result of an aggregate function to a textbox that resides inside the GroupFooterCellStyle of a column in my radgridview.

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewGroupFooterCell" x:Key="RadGridViewGroupFooterCellStyleTest">
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"></Setter>
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TotalUnitsPostRegDC}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Whenever I use a fixed text, it works. When I try to use the example above, the textbox shows up empty.

This is how I render the whole colum:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Total" ColumnGroupName="UnitsPostReg" DataMemberBinding="{Binding TotalUnitsPostRegDC}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" Width="100" IsGroupable="False" GroupFooterCellStyle="{StaticResource RadGridViewGroupFooterCellStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" ValidatesOnDataErrors="None">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
        <telerik:SumFunction />
        <views:TotalUnitsPostRegDC />
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What's `views:TotalUnitsPostRegDC` in your AggregateFunctions collection?

Comment: Three things are required for any binding to happen 1) DataContext 2) Proper binding to that thing in XAML or elsewhere and 3) The actual content.  Set a breakpoint in the control you want to see that data at initialization time, look for when the data context is set (assuming it's not static in the XAML)... Then put a break on the property getter setter and see if it's called, if not then the binding isn't correct.  If it is called but nothing shows, then the code is not notifying property changed properly.  Finally make sure the value is there.